# bufio.NewScanner as a function argument

Tags: go

I have this code:

```
var scanner = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)

func readInt() int {
    scanner.Scan()
    ans, _ := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    return ans
}

func main() {
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    n := readInt()

    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

Now, the `scanner` variable is global. And I want to make it local and pass it to `readInt()` function as a parameter. When I tried this way it would not work:

```
func readInt(scanner bufio.NewScanner) int {
    scanner.Scan()
    ans, _ := strconv.Atoi(scanner.Text())
    return ans
}

func main() {
    var scanner = bufio.NewScanner(os.Stdin)
    scanner.Split(bufio.ScanWords)

    n := readInt(scanner)

    fmt.Println(n)
}
```

If someone could give a hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`bufio.NewScanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#NewScanner) is a function for creating a new scanner:

> `func NewScanner(r io.Reader) *Scanner`
>   NewScanner returns a new Scanner to read from r. The split function defaults to ScanLines.

not a type that you can use in a function signature. However, `bufio.NewScanner` returns a `*bufio.Scanner` and [`bufio.Scanner`](https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner) is a type so you could say:

```
func readInt(scanner *bufio.Scanner) int {
    //...
}
```